# Marionette fetch User on login from node.js

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, marionette

I have a tricky problem, i have got a Marionette Application based on a node.js backend which uses express-resource to access the database.

I use a middleware to ensure a logged-in user, if not the user is redirected to a login page which is served by node directly. After login the user has got a session cookie and is forwarded to the Marionette App.

The application doesnt know the user. In order to get the user i wil have to get it via an ajax call. The problem is, i don't know the users id because the session token doesnt contain this information.

My solution is: There are two resources in the api, one to get accounts in general and one to get only the current user. This is a kind of duplication of resources i want to avoid.

How to do this properly?

Comment: How did you end up solving this problem. I am having the same issue, did you avoid adding business logic in your backbone views

Comment: i added a cookie to the reply containing the user id. I then read the cookie by jquery cookie. I use a singleton pattern for the user model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply add the user id to the session cookie..

btw - make sure your backend accesses only the authenticated user's resources (according to the session) and that you don't have to provide the user id to AJAX calls. maybe you can actually avoid knowing the user id ?

Comment: yes i had the idea of adding the user id to the session cookie. The backend ensures the resources are accessed only if allowed. Maybe thats the best way